# Configure wireless Adapter on VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, wifi

So the reason I am writing here is because I did not find a solution for this problem anywhere else. Hence, Kindly read the whole post before marking it as a duplicate thread. And if indeed, this question is answered, kindly lead me to it.

So I have a Dell XPS 13 9350 with Windows 10 on it. I installed Virtual Box and run Windows 7 on it. Now here is the problem, the network adapter works fine but it shows as an ethernet adapter and not as a wireless adapter. And I want it to be a wireless adapter so I can connect it to the EZCast Dongle I use.

Here is what I have done so far -

1. I have left the Virtual Box network preference to default
2. I have changed the network adapter to Bridge Mode & selected my Wlan adapter on the VM machine settings

Kindly request you all to help me out with this.

Cheers, 
Jesse

Comment: This question is off topic. Anyway, your virtual machine is running on virtual hardware. Having a VirtualBox interface emulating a wifi adapter is unlikely to change the problem you are facing. Please explain what this problem is, not how you want to fix it.

Comment: I want to use the EZcast Dongle on my laptop. How that works is, you need to connect to the EZCast wifi network after which you get access to the app that controls the dongle. So my question is how can I connect the Guest separately to the EZcast dongle, while my Host is still connected to the existing home network.

Answer (score 2):

Connect your dongle with host. Enable USB in virtual box settings and select the dongle. 
 save configuration and reboot your guest.

Ex:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to download and install  [the Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) to enable USB ports.